# Fire validations on button click (Java swing)

Tags: java, swing, validation

Have a Java Swing app designed for touch screens (big buttons all over the place) with a lot of forms composed, as usual, with input fields (textbox, combos, checkboxes, radios,...) + a button to save the data.

I need a "generic" way to implement validators (required, numeric only, regular expresion, ...) that fire on button's click showing a validation summary (likely on a message box), pretty much like ASP .NET's validators system, where you assign a bunch of validators to your input fields within the same validation group together with your button, and click event is not fired until every validator passes the test.

The question is how to implement or which framework to use for this validation style?

So far I've seen 3 options on the web and none of them fit my needs:

- Java Swing's InputVerfier class: this is simple and nice but works when input losts focus and would be really annoying for a touch screen user.
- Simple Validation API: it's the closest API for my validation style but it seems to be tightly coupled to a validation panel that shows errors on bottom. I can use a variation of this API to change the way it presents errors on screen.
- JGoodies validation: seems too powerful but couldn't find any simple example and I'm not implementing any model pattern as it seems to be needed with this framework.

Answer (score 0):

OVal (http://http://oval.sourceforge.net/) may fully satisfy your needs.

Let's imagine you have a placeholder for all values coming from your form. It can be constructed and populated with the actual data when user submits the form.
OVal allows you to define constraints for class fields:

```
public class BusinessObject {

  @NotNull
  @NotEmpty
  @Length(max=32)
  private String name;

  ...
}
```

Having that defined you can easily trigger validation procedure. OVal will supply you with a list of violations, so you can easily construct your summary dialogue.

```
Validator validator = new Validator();
BusinessObject bo = new BusinessObject();

// collect the constraint violations
List<ConstraintViolation> violations = validator.validate(bo);
```

You can get rid of intermediate placeholders by using getters constraints.

```
public class BusinessObject {

  @IsInvariant
  @NotNull 
  @Length(max = 4)
  public String getName() {
  ...
  }
}
```

Please note, OVal follows clean design principle and can be easily extended. Anyway, it provides quite a lot of power out of the box:

- conditional constraints using expression languages
- constraints for nested properties
- recursive validation
- constraints for method parameters
- scripted expressions for preconditions
- method return value constraints
- probe mode to simplify UI user input validation
- and much more

Please see http://oval.sourceforge.net/userguide.html